# can't download new windows desktop gadgets

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, desktop-gadget

I've set up the pre-installed Windows 7 (enterprise) desktop gadgets on my laptop (weather, news), and would like to download & install some more from Microsoft's online offering. But when I find an interesting gadget and click download (using IE 9), nothing happens. No download, no error message, no security bar to confirm my action. Doesn't matter if I'm using an administrator account or not. Anyone else having this problem or knows of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should download a `.gadget` file.  Then you need to double click that gadget file to install it.

You shouldn't need to be an admin to install gadgets, but if you are part of a domain, your work has the option of disabling gadgets.

Comment: thanks for the info. for some reason, it's working now in IE9.